# git auto deployment is not working

Tags: git, github, deployment

I am working on git auto deployment. I have my repo on local machine as well as on server. I want to push my changes automatically on server when i will push it from my local machine. In bitbucket I have setup service as POST as well as setup hook POST with the URL of the file which I want to execute on push event. My hook is getting called on each push but it is not letting it to pull latest changes on server. Also I have printed my payload into deploy.log file which is as below.

```
s:677:"{"repository":{  
   "website":"",
   "fork":false,
   "name":"Test_df_2014",
   "scm":"git",
   "owner":"ABC_USER",
   "absolute_url":"/ABC_USER/test_df_2014/",
   "slug":"test_df_2014",
   "is_private":true
},
"truncated":false,
"commits":[  
   {  
      "node":"1462100cabcd",
      "files":[  
         {  
            "type":"modified",
            "file":"test.php"
         }
      ],
      "raw_author":"abc <abc.xyz@gmail.com>",
      "utctimestamp":"2015-07-28 11:42:52+00:00",
      "author":"ABC_USER",
      "timestamp":"2015-07-28 13:42:52",
      "raw_node":"1462100cabcd1eb4ba0d63b4047d71226246ea90",
      "parents":[  
         "3da591a3f31e"
      ],
      "branch":"master",
      "message":"testing 20\n",
      "revision":null,
      "size":-1
   }
],
"canon_url":"https://bitbucket.org",
"user":"ABC_USER"
}";N;
```

I tried it with git pull, git fetch, git pull origin master..but no luck.
Also checked file permissions. All is set. shell_exec also enabled on my server.
Can anyone help me with this. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where does GitHub come into play?

Comment: Hi  bitoiu..thank you so much for your attention. But fortunately issue is solved. thank again :) :)

Comment: you should post the answer then and clarify the question a bit more as well.

Comment: hi..it was my mistake..I was trying to push my changes into wrong repository and  then I change repository name from hook.php and finally it worked :)

Comment: Here i am explaining what i have done. First I connected my github with my server through SSH key. Then i clone repository on my server( git clone) as well as on my local machine.then in git hub under settings->service I choose post service and then hook as a post and gave url of the script(hook.php) which is placed on server. so on every push my hook.php gets called. In hook.php i hv written my code which will pull content from github to server using shell_exec(). thats it. :) and it worked :)